# Show $\log_2(1+x)\geq x/4$ when $0<x\leq 15$

Tags: calculus, analysis, inequality, logarithms

> Prove $\log_2(1+x)\geq x/4$ when $0<x\leq 15$.

How can we solve this? I used Taylor expansion and it did not work.

Comment: Hint: If $f(x)$ is concave for $x\in[0,15]$, then$$f(x)\ge\frac{f(15)-f(0)}{15}x$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that

$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\log_2(x+1)=-\frac1{(x+1)^2\ln(2)}<0$$

Thus, $\log_2(x+1)$ is concave and it is bounded below by its secant lines and bounded above by its tangent lines, mainly, on the interval $[0,15]$, we have the bounds

$$\frac x4=\frac{\log_2(15+1)-\log_2(0+1)}{15}x\le\log_2(x+1)\le x\lim_{t\to0}\frac d{dt}\log_2(t+1)=\frac x{\ln(2)}$$

Comment: @ Simply Beautiful Art. Nice! Please elaborate: $y= (1/4) x  \le y_1 =[ log_2(16) - log_2(1)]/15 x $(secant line)$ \le log_2(1+x), x \in (0,15]$, since concave, lower bound. Correct? It goes on: $\le$ tangent of  $log_2(1+x)$ at $x=0$. Upper bound. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.